# Can I (mis-)use a CAN bus line for phantom power?

Tags: can

I just looked at the datasheet of the [TJA1050 CAN transceiver](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/TJA1050.pdf) and noticed that both CANL and CANH tolerate -27 to +40 V.

Standards aside, does that mean I could pull the entire CAN bus to e.g. 12V to provide power to devices along the bus? With GND running along a chassis, would that make it a 2 wire data- and powerbus solution?

edit: Even if the transceiver would not tolerate that, it should still be possible to do it the old-fashioned way by adding input capacitors to decouple the transceiver from the phantom power, right?

Comment: I guess it depends how would you pull the bus to 12V. Can you draw a schematic?

Comment: That rating means that the transceiver should _survive_ an accidental short to 12VDC/24VDC, not that it guarantees that meaningful data transmission will be possible at the same time as there is an accidental short circuit present on the bus. The dominant state for either CAN line will 2.5V, in which case the transceiver will actively drive that signal level. Also, using chassis for signal ground is a really bad idea in general. Just as inventing some secret 2-wire non-standard is a really bad idea.

Comment: @Lundin I don't mind the secret standard bit, I am mostly looking for arguments on how to improve the status quo in Velomobile wiring. Currently that is routing 6 wires from the middle to the front of the vehicle to control 5 lights (and more to other parts of the vehicle). Reducing that to 2 or 3 wires (signal and power) would be great.

Comment: The CAN transceiver will *survive* -27V..+40V on the differential lines. But when transmitting a dominant bit, it'll drive CAN_H to 3.0..4.25V and CAN_L to 0.5..1.75V. And during recessive bits both lines will be between 2.0..3.0V.

Comment: You'd get (at least) 4 signals with conventional CAN, assuming you use supply GND as signal reference. I would imagine it's all about quality vs price - having a CAN node in each light sounds a bit luxurious perhaps?

Comment: @Velvel Ah yeah that's what my previous comment should say - I mixed up the dominant and recessive levels. Can't edit comments...

Comment: Anyway, what is the actual problem here? Why is 6 wires a problem? Is the actual problem a cabling one? Is the problem cable thickness, EMC, what?

Comment: _"Even if the transceiver would not tolerate that"_ It *does* tolerate those voltages. That's the point. _"..by adding input capacitors to decouple the transceiver from the phantom power"_ That sounds like a bad idea. CAN is robust when implemented properly. But I've come to the conclusion that it very easily backfires when being abused. Just do it the proper way and add two separate V+/GND lines.

Comment: @Lundin Standard CAN PHYs allow -2 to +7V common mode, this chip in question seems to allow for -12 to +12V, so it might just work receiving, and for transmitting it should be able to pull CANL down and hit the current limit. Even if this is a gimmick, it might work, but then again, single wire CAN does exist so it could be used instead.

Comment: There are ways to multiplex power lines for various purposes, but CAN is not one of them: it needs DC coupling so you can't also send DC power through it. For example, Ethernet is AC coupled so can be multiplexed with DC (power over Ethernet); see also communication over powerline schemes (ranging from home intercoms to Ethernet and more).

Comment: @Justme It's just some way they write it in the datasheet. Looking at another one MCP2562FD which also has "Normal Mode;
-12V < V( CANH , CANL) < +12V;" as some sort of reference, it leaves a note "-12V to 12V is ensured by characterization, tested from -2V to 7V". I'm not sure what they mean by this, but it seems to be some sort of convention.

Comment: @Lundin The overarching problem to solve is that velomobiles are still based on last centuries tech. In the end that is not a bad thing as just running wires to lights is relatively easy to maintain by end users. The thing is that there are more and more tinkerers that add more electronics to their VMs ... high- & low beams, turn signals, brake lights but also wheel rpm or temperature sensors. So in the end the problem here is to implement a system that is extendable without running more and more wires through the vehicle. Having a low wire count system is just a good selling point.

Comment: @fho As is adhering to industry standards. So it would seem that standard CAN used as intended would solve all your problems?

Comment: @Lundin Sure, using a standard CAN is the plan right now. I just noticed that there might be an opportunity to reduce the amount of wiring.

Comment: @fho Or you can use standardized M12 5 pin connectors or such, so that you also get standardized pin-out, with shield as an option. It's an advantage to mechanics and similar if they can buy standard parts from multiple vendors, instead of having to buy "Bob's special cable assembly for the purpose of making things complicated", which can only be purchased from Bob.